# Why does this sentence only use a "ne"?

Tags: négation, comparatifs, ne-explétif

I was reading "Les Misérables" and I have come across this sentence where I don't understand why there is only a "ne" without any other negation word.

> […] C'était une âme plus encore que ce n'était une vierge. […]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Il s'agit ici d'un *ne* explétif utilisé dans une proposition comparative, il n'est pas obligatoire. Il est la plupart du temps omis à l'oral.

Grévisse :

> Après *plus, moins, mieux, autre, autrement, meilleur, moindre, pire,
>   plutôt*, marquant une comparaison d'inégalité, le verbe de la seconde
>   proposition prend souvent *ne* quand la principale est affirmative.

Grévisse ajoute en note de bas de page que l'Office de la Langue française (dans le *Littéraire*, 29 mars 1947) en prenant l'exemple de 
« Vous êtes plus grand que vous croyez » et « que vous ne croyez » que le *ne* marque une insistance sur le fait. Donc dans la phrase d'Hugo on pourrait dire que la présence du *ne* insiste encore plus sur le fait que chez mademoiselle Baptistine c'est vraiment l'âme qui compte.

Pour un lecteur du XXI<sup>ème</sup> siècle, qui ne mettrait pas *ne* dans ce genre de subordonnée dans la langue parlée de tous les jours, sa  présence  renforce l'aspect littéraire de la langue employée par Hugo.