# « Plus que vous croyez », « que vous le croyez » ou « que vous ne le croyez » ?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, comparatifs, ne-explétif

Vu sur le site du [Défi têtes rasées Leucan](http://www.tetesrasees.com/fr/nouvelle/votre-tete-vaut-plus-que-vous-pensez-et-donner-rend-plus-leger) :

> Votre tête vaut plus que vous pensez

La Banque Scotia au Québec possède le slogan suivant :

> Vous êtes plus riche que vous le croyez.

Enfin, la dernière campagne publicitaire d'Apple en France pour son iPhone 5s s'intitule :

> Vous avez plus de pouvoirs que vous ne l'imaginez.

Toutes ces phrases veulent faire passer le même message, à savoir que le lecteur se trompe sur l'importance qu'il accorde à un sujet ou à un objet, mais utilisent trois constructions différentes :

1. que vous + (verbe à la 2e personne du pluriel)
2. que vous le + (verbe à la 2e personne du pluriel)
3. que vous ne le + (verbe à la 2e personne du pluriel)

Ces trois tournures sont-elles correctes ? Y aurait-il des différences de sens qui m'auraient échappé ?

Comment: Lié: http://french.stackexchange.com/q/8204/79

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pour la première phrase, elle n'est ni fausse ni juste.

La formulation correcte serait

> Votre tête vaut plus que vous ne le pensez

Cependant, le ton et le niveau de langage employé par tetesrasees.com est familier. En langage familier, on aurait donc tendance à supprimer *ne le*.

Pour la seconde… il faudrait attendre l'avis d'un québécois. En tant que français, je trouve ça légèrement inapproprié (là encore, le registre n'est pas le bon)… Mais bon, le jour où les banques feront des choses appropriées…

Pour la 3ème, la phrase est 100% correcte.

Dans tous les cas, le sens reste le même avec ou sans *ne* ou *ne le*, il n'y a aucune ambiguïté, ni dans l'intention de l'auteur, ni dans la formulation.

Comment: Au Québec, nous avons tendance à supprimer (en langage familier) la négation dans ce genre de phrase. C'est pour cette raison que les exemples *1* et *2* sont correcte ici. Deplus, comme vous l'avez mentionné, cela ne met aucune ambiguïté dans la phrase, donc le sens de la phrase n'en est pas altéré. Je dois cependant aussi ajouter que, personellement, je trouve que l'exemple *1* se dirait mieux ainsi : *"Votre tête vaut plus que vous l'pensez"* (Langage familier)

Answer (score 1):

On ne compare en quantité que des choses comparables.
La première phrase compare le fait de valoir au fait de penser. Elle est donc incorrecte.
Dans la seconde, « le » signifie « être riche » :

« Vous êtes plus riche que vous croyez être riche ».

On compare « être riche » en pensée avec « être riche » en réalité. C'est correct.

Pour la 3ème, le « ne » n'a aucun sens ni fonction mais est admis.

Notons que l'anglais est plus strict à ce point de vue. Le français dira : « il est plus grand que moi ».
L'anglais dira souvent : « il est plus grand que je [ne] le suis ».

C'est toujours sous-entendu en français. La rhétorique prend des raccourcis.