# Dangling(?) "le" in some French translations

Tags: grammaire, traduction, pronoms-personnels

I've noticed in some French translations from English, there seems to be the use of "le" in sentences with seemingly no antecedent:

For example, Scotiabank's motto "*You're richer than you think*" becomes

[image]

Similarly, the common warning on car mirrors "*Objects are closer than they appear*" becomes

[image]

In both cases, I don't know why "le" appears before the final verb. When learning French in school, I was taught that "le" can serve as a direct object pronoun referring to something earlier in the sentence, like

> J'ai vu **un livre rouge** et je **l**'ai acheté.

However, in the cases

> Vous êtes plus riche que vous **le** croyez
>
> Les objets réfléchis par le rétroviseur sont plus près qu'ils ne **le** paraissent

it's not clear what "le" refers to (especially in the second sentence, where "objets" is plural).

Does this particular phenomenon have a name in French? I apologize if this has already been asked; it is just confusing for me as a French learner.

Comment: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/29493/emploi-du-pronom-neutre-le

Comment: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11427/plus-que-vous-croyez-que-vous-le-croyez-ou-que-vous-ne-le-croyez